# Russian For: No Smoking!

Tags: словоупотребление

In England there are no-smoking signs at certain places.

What would be written in Russian? For: **No Smoking!**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, they just write **"Не курить!"**
A more polite form: **"У нас не курят!"**
There is also more strict option: **"Курение (строго) запрещено!"**.
Sanctions for violating this ban are also frequently mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer!